# How can I create a class A in C#, where A can only be inherited by B, C, D?

Tags: c#, .net, inheritance

There is some mechanism to allow a class to be inherited by N classes only in C#?

Comment: Are `B`, `C` and `D` in the same assembly?

Comment: Does this need to be at run time or compile time.

Comment: Is there a specific reason for you to do that? Perhaps an actual example will help.

Comment: It would be interesting if any one could come with a hack for this

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You may put it and it's derived classes in a separate assembly, and declare the constructor of the base class as `internal`. That way although you could inherit from it in a different assembly, but you wouldn't be able to instantiate any derived class.

Comment: How can you inherit but not be able to instantiate?

Comment: @Mehrdad: Since the derived class calls the base's constructor, it must have access to that constructor. Putting the access to `internal` only allows derived classes in the same assembly (or friend assemblies) to call the base.  It should also be noted that the derived classes should be `sealed`.

Comment: @Travis: But how can you enforce that the derived classes aren't instantiated?

Comment: Set the constructor as private, and then no one can call it.

Comment: If i am not wrong the OP wants to put a number to the number of classes than can inherit from a specific class,rest instantiation should be as it happens

Comment: @recursive: But then you can't inherit it either.

Comment: Well, yes, inheriting requires the ability to instantiate.  You asked how to ensure that they weren't instantiated.

Comment: @recursive: It was obviously in the context of my first comment: `How can you inherit but not be able to instantiate?`

Comment: I assumed you meant not be able to instantiate the sub-classes.  Private constructors on those subclasses does allow that.

Comment: thanks for this. exactly what I needed. need classes from the same assembly be able to inherit from an abstract class but the abstract class should not inheritable from a different assembly. tried setting the abstract class as internal but got a compile error that the accessibility is not consistent. this however, solves that. thanks!

Answer (score 4):

No, but you can always make the constructor throw an exception if it exceeds the limit.

Comment: Record types of `this` in a hashtable in the base class constructor.

Answer (score 4):

```
// can be inherited only by classes in the same assembly
public abstract class A
{
    protected internal A() { }
}

// can't be inherited
public sealed class B : A
{
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just for my personal edification, I'd like to know more about the business context which make such a design choice desirable, since my first thougt at reading the title was "Oh, very very bad idea ! A base class is NEVER supposed to know anything (and worse : to rule) its derived classes".

Comment: I can create a tagged union of B, C, and D by having an empty base class A from which B C and D but no other classed inherit.

Answer (score -1):

You can make the class A abstarct and inherit it in any number of classes..

Comment: I think in this case that N=3

Comment: @Tom : please see the answer given by Abatishchev , I just wanted to tell the same.. I thought after the hint, rest the questioner can google...